# How do I execute a specific version of Maven plugin goal from command line using plugin prefix?

Tags: maven

I want to execute `mvn dependency:get` from command line. I have 3 versions of `maven-dependency-plugin` installed locally: 2.1, 2.8 and 3.2.0. Maven is selecting 2.8 to execute the command.

How do I tell Maven to use 3.2.0 instead? Most of the time I would like to run LATEST (or RELEASE). How does Maven choose the version? I know that I can use full name to specify version but I prefer the short syntax with plugin prefix.

Comment: Usually you should define the plugin version via pluginManagement in your pom file. Second via command line you can give: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:get` (something like `LATEST` or `RELEASE` does not exist). The decision is made based on the Maven Version you are using. That's the reason why you should always define plugins via pluginMangement...If you like to use short variant you have to define via pom...

Comment: I don't have a pom. It's not in a context of any Maven project.

Comment: Then why are you calling maven-dependency-pugin at all? In which environment? (local, CI ?)?

Comment: Local, but you have answered my question. Version 2.8 comes from Super POM. If I want to override it, I should define pom.xml. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, to select `maven-dependency-plugin` in version 3.2.0:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:get
```

It can differ from what is defined in your settings/pom.xml.

Reference: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/jboss-maven/how-to-invoke-a-maven-plugin-from-the-command-line/